# TextBox Foreground color in jquery

Tags: jquery

Why isn't this piece of code working?

```
$("#TextOne").animate({ color: "#FFFF00" }, 800);
```

When i call it on a button click it does nothing. I have Chrome.

Answer (score 3):

Are you using the [color plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery.color.js.txt) (or jQuery UI)?

Without one of these it won't work because jQuery does not natively support the animation of color properties.

Answer (score 3):

You can't fade colors :( You need **[Color plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color)** for that :)

Comment: *wondering why I've got no votes yet posted 1 minute before you :(*

Comment: @J-P: Not sure either but +1 from my side :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

define a css color like this.

```
.anim-color
    {
        color:##FFFF00;
    }
```

animate on a class like this.

```
$("#TextOne").animate({ className: 'anim-color' }, 800);
```