# How-to: text input fadeout

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Jquery fadeout text insde a text box and textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297077/jquery-fadeout-text-insde-a-text-box-and-textarea)
>   [TextBox Foreground color in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317369/textbox-foreground-color-in-jquery)

Hi,

How can I fade out input and textarea values? All my attempts result in fading out the whole elements, not their content.

Thanks in advance!

Mike

Comment: Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/bradchristie/2CswJ/) perhaps? (Note, you need jQuery UI, or at the very least the [color plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery.color.js.txt))

Comment: @Brad, What if the input has a background image rather than a simple color?

Comment: Then I believe you're SOL without playing with opacity and visibility (and/or wrapping the whole thing in style elements to give you the flexibility of visual effect).

Comment: @Brad, I'm not sure what you mean? Would you mind explaining more?

Comment: Let's put it another way: Controls (the input, select box, textarea, etc.) in it of themself are not very flexible, because of the "hard implementation" that comes with them. Browsers give you some flexibility with customization, but not much (all things considered). To achieve what you're after, you're either going to have to settle for making the fore color change (but not background, as this is one of those fixed settings), or remake the control using things like span, div, etc. elements so you have more control than what's offered out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same effect by manipulating the `color` of the text - animating it to or from the background-color of the text-field so it seems to 'fade' out or in, respectively.

The `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` methods that jQuery provides animate the `opacity` property of elements. As you've seen, doing that on a `textarea` or `<input type="text">` will change the opacity of the entire element.

I would make the distinction between fading which I understand to be a change in opacity and this animation of the color but as pointed out below, they may be regarded as different means to the same end with the end being important.

**Reference**:

Here's (pretty much) the same question: [Jquery fadeout text insde a text box and textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297077/jquery-fadeout-text-insde-a-text-box-and-textarea)

Comment: The answer is wrong anyway; jQuery UI allows the animation of textbox foreground colour.

Comment: Isn't that what I said with '*The other way might be to animate the color CSS property of the input element to make it 'fade' in from, say, white to black*'? If you mean where I said '*you can't*', well you're not actually 'fading' it by animating the `color`, are you? You're simulating fading by modifying the color, not the actually opacity which is what (at least as I understand it) fading is.

Comment: @no.good: Ah yes I guess it is. I don't see why you just tacked it on to the "long version" bit, when it's a short, easy and canonical solution to the problem.

Comment: @no.good: Fading the internal text might as well mean changing the colour, as you have a fixed background to work with. "Fading" refers to what the user sees, not how you do it.

Comment: Hm, you're probably right, I'll update the answer with that option first and add the disclaimer that it's not actually 'fading'.

Comment: @no.good.at.coding, Good 'workaround', but what if the input has a background image?

Comment: @Hermes Then this hack won't work and I can't think of anything else that's quite as simple and straightforward. A solution for that might to use a [`contenteditable`](http://html5demos.com/contenteditable) element instead but that might involve writing a lot of code to get fields that look and behave like the standard browser controls - unless you can find a library that already lets you do that. Facebook, for example, uses this approach for at least some of their input fields.

Comment: A second approach as suggested on the SO page I linked to, is to replace the text input field with a look-alike div or span and animate that instead. When you're done animating, swap the div/span back out for the original text field. I might be wrong but I personally think this might end up being a lot more complicated than building a custom control because for example, you don't want to have your user wait until your animations finish before he can interact with the text field again.

Comment: [Here's a jQuery plugin](http://valums.com/edit-in-place/) that might help you if you pick using the `contenteditable` approach. There might be better ones, I haven't looked too hard!